# Differentiable function which sends rationals to rationals and irrationals to irrationals

Tags: functions, continuity

> Function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. It is also continuous and has derivative for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Does the condition that there are no points $x\in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $f(x) \in \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$ and no points $x \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ such that $f(x) \in \mathbb{Q}$ imply that  $f$ is a linear function?

I tried to construct a counterexample, however I did not succeed. Are there any ideas, please?

Comment: In fact, there is a function that isn't linear that satisfies the above properties. But a similar problem, i.e. a function that switches the rationality of the argument cannot be continuous let alone differentiable.

Comment: oh, I did not see it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: How about $f(x) = x^3$? In fact, won't any non-constant polynomial do?

Comment: @Thumbnail its not corect because $f(\sqrt[3]{2})=2$

Comment: Piecewise rational functions work, as $1/x$ and related satisfy the criterion. (I say "piecewise" because you need to avoid the singularity at $0$)

Answer (score 0):

You can  take  a translation of a linear function.

For instance take $f(x)=x+1$  which is an affine function.

This function is not linear( because $f(2)=3 \neq f(1)+f(1)=4$) and satisfies the above conditions.

Also notice that the converse is not true.

Take for instance $f(x)= \sqrt{2}x$.

This is a linear function everywhere differentiable but $f(\sqrt{2})=2$

Comment: By linear they mean $ax+b$ (affine). But yeah the terminology is horrible

Comment: Every linear function is an affine function but the converse is not true.The O.P asks about linear functions.